# When is the dispersion parameter estimated in a GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, dispersion

I'm looking at some notes online and I can see that in the example given, the dispersion parameter is estimated when we have a Gaussian model, but not when we use a Poisson model. Why is this? Is there a general rule to know when it is estimated (and hence whether you get t or z-values in the GLM output)?

Comment: Note that the Poisson model *does not have a dispersion parameter*, since the variance equals the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you can express dispersion independently of location**, you estimate the dispersion parameter. For example, the mean of a Gaussian distribution gives you no information about its variance, hence we will express the variance as pure dispersion.

**If that is not the case, you use the variance function** (*equivalent to say that the dispersion parameter is set to 1*). This function relates both mean and variance. In the case of a Poisson distribution, the lambda parameter determines both.

As a third scenario, if you have overdispersion, both apply.